# A Linear Function being Invertible is Equivalent to its Determinant being Invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $M$ be a finite-rank free $R$-module, where $R$ is a commutative ring (with identity), and let $L$ be an endomorphism of $M$. How do I prove that $L$ is bijective if and only if it's determinate is invertible?

Comment: If the determinant is invertible, use the explicit inverse formula for matrices. If $L$ is bijective, it's invertible -- so consider the determinant of its inverse.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Use the formula
$$
A \operatorname{adj}(A) = \det(A) I,
$$
where $\operatorname{adj}(A)$ denotes the [adjugate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix).